# mpg123 control via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, mp3

I´m trying to find a way to control the playing of mpg123 via a bash script. E.g. play or pause the song. I´m using Debian Stretch.

I found out there´s a a kind of remote-mode on mpg123 (mpg123 -R). For now, the song is just played directly and there´s no possibility to control it.

```
sudo mpg123 /var/www/html/resources/audio/Rock/test.mp3
```

I´m rather new to Linux, so I don´t completely understand e.g. this guide: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame/blob/master/deps/mpg123/doc/README.remote
When starting mpg123 in remote mode, how can I write to stdin (or fifo, whatever that means here) via bash?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not going to go in-depth about this, but here are some ways to call your program:


; via stdin: `cat audioFile.mp3 | mpg123`



; as a redirection of stdin: `mpg123 <audioFile.mp3` 



; via a fifo: `mpg123 --fifo /tmp/myAudioFifo` ( <- this creates a "listener"), and `echo HELP > /tmp/myAydioFifo` ( <- this sends a message to the listener via the fifo).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the fifo (had to add the --remote option), now it works! `mpg123 --remote --fifo ~/mpg123fifo`